# How to catch exceptions generated by packages in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-5

I am working with a package called [tymondesigns/jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) in Laravel 5 and it generates exceptions like `TokenExpiredException`, `TokenInvalidException` and so on. I would like to catch these exceptions and return JSON responses for them. I have tried this in the `Handler.php` file:

```
if ($e instanceof TokenExpiredException) {
    return jsend()->error()
              ->message("Token has Expired")
              ->data([null])
              ->get();
}
```

But in vain. How to catch these exceptions and return JSON responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing namespace, try to catch it with

```
if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException) {
    return jsend()->error()
              ->message("Token has Expired")
              ->data([null])
              ->get();
}
```

Comment: I tried that in a use statement above but I guess I was missing something small somewhere. Thanks. :)